# Should users with reputation over 20k be able to direct message?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I've recently received a comment on one of my posts by a high rep user with a tip regarding reviewing posts. This seems like a poor way to convey a message to someone, but it was his only option and his message was useful.

Should users with reputation over 20k be able to direct message other users?

**I should add:**

- If the high-rep user comments on an unrelated question to communicate with
  me, isn't that abusing the comments section?
- Also, what if the high-rep user would like to contact a user who has never
  asked a question?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, I don't think they should. If that tip was helpful to you, it's probably going to be helpful to other people who read it as well. If people want to be contacted privately, they'll leave their info in their profile. Other than that, only moderators should privately contact users in the rare cases where that's necessary.

Comment: Since the comment wasn't pertinent to the question. IE, he found a random question of mine and contacted me there, I find it hard to believe it would be useful to anyone. Also, what if I had never asked a question, how would he have contacted me?

Comment: @DanBeaulieu If you had never asked/answered a question, I'd contact you at the Twitter account you listed in your profile.

Comment: fair enough, I suppose my view of a moderator vs. high rep was a bit fuzzy, thanks for clearing that up