# How to notify or message a specific user

Tags: discussion, chat, users

Within some questions, I find that a user appears to have particular knowledge that might be helpful in addressing other questions that they (probably) have not seen yet. How would I go about notifying a particular user to please take a look at the other question and provide any feedback they can on it?

Is there a way to start a chat with a user other than posting too many comments back and forth on a particular thread? If not, I'd like to make this a feature request, to post a message to a particular user outside the context of a particular question.

Comment: The potential for abuse of this "feature" is huge.  Why would I want random users pinging me?  Ask good questions well, tag them properly, and the users able to answer will see it.

Comment: But once a question goes off the first page of recent, it becomes more and more unlikely to ever be answered.

Comment: Yes, that's the definition of "recent".  Be patient, as not everyone who can answer looks at the site in real time or even daily.  If you can narrow or enhance the question in the meantime, that will bump it.  You can also set a bounty to draw attention.  But in no way is pinging users a good way to "solve" this.

Comment: You have plenty of rep, why not try putting a bounty on.

Comment: Why the downvotes? If this question can be improved, please make suggestions. If not, well, I can't delete it now.

Comment: They're meta-downvotes, they don't count. On a feature-request (which this sort of is), this means people don't want that feature.

Comment: but also, as on the main site, do your research first: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296572/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272503/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250160/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255669/ http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261885/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Sure: you can invite a user to chat.

1. Go to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com).
2. Switch to the "users" tab at the top of the page:

[image: Users tab]

3. Switch to the "all" tab in the top right corner of the page:

[image: All tab]

4. Search for the user you'd like to contact using the search field and click on the correct result to go to their profile.
5. On that profile, click the "start a new room with this user" button:

[image: Start a new room with this user]

That user will then receive a notification that you have invited them to join a room.

**However, you really shouldn't be using this to ask someone to answer your question(s) for you**; there are countless duplicates stating why that isn't allowed. This should be used to contact a specific user about something specific that requires their immediate attention.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the etiquette tip as well. That's rather disappointing to hear since I really don't know anyone else who might be able to answer my question.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts the fact that you don't *know* anyone who can answer is the point of this site: the experts follow the tags they can answer, they find you.  Just because you got an answer from one user doesn't mean there are no others out there who can answer too.

Comment: Also note that 99.99% of the time, you can find a chat profile simply by adding `chat.` in front of a user URL. For AstroCB for an instance: `https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb` or `https://stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb` becomes `https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/3366929/astrocb`. (stackoverflow.com is prepended with `chat.`, while the meta.stackoverflow.com has meta replaced with chat). This has failed a few times in the past, and I'm fairly certain that's from account merge artifacts, but it works a lot of the time.

Comment: The search functionality is unusable. If i had discussion with someone on comments of a question, i can't directly find this user later on by his ID, instead you should use the nickname search which is overly elastic (and not unique on SO)