# Is there an easy way to learn more about why flags are declined?

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, declined-flags, feature-request-process

I flagged a duplicate, not helpful answer with just source code (rated -6 already) and another one which had (in my mind) nothing at all to do with a question.

Curiously, both flags got declined with the reason "declined - there are already processes which do this automatically". I accept that, but I would love to have more information on that, **it would be great if the reasons for a flag would be clickable and linked to a definition**.

For the particular case, it got even more interesting: I checked the user who reviewed the flags and it turns out to be the same one. Plus one with an interestingly low reputation of 1, being member for just five months, and no further description. I would understand that it would be a bot, but even then, I would love to have an easy ways to have a veto or at least ask for another review.

So what do I do now? Can someone have a look into those particular flags? And what about my suggestions about the flagging process?

**EDIT:** **All I am asking for is more transparency for the standard user concerning the flagging process.** Somebody sees a very strong need to flag, a single person (or bot) does not see that need, issue closed. I believe this process can be improved, e.g. by allow the initial user to veto, by asking another reviewer or two (maybe of same reputation range).

Comment: What kind of flags did you raise? What did you want should happen to the answers and why did that need to happen to them? How can we review anything if you don't provide infomation about which posts you flagged?

Comment: How is that a [tag:feature-request]?

Comment: @RoberLongson: There are quite some useless answers around with negative values, and I thought flagging them for deletion might speed up their deletion. What I would love to have is some more information on the deletion process per se.

Comment: I will edit the post to highlight my feature request.

Comment: A comment and a downvote mean two different things. Why should I comment if I mean 'this question isn't useful'?

Comment: Also: we can't see what you flag. Only diamond mods can. If you want to get the community's help, we'll need more details: what kind of flags were they? (I guess custom flags from your question) what was the text you put in the flags? On which posts were they?

Comment: Many people (including me) perceive a downvote *without a comment* as demotivating, unwelcoming, maybe even rude. As I said: It is my first post here, and I am not sure I would do it again.

Comment: @Patrice The tipp with the *diamond mods* is helpful.

Comment: Sure. If that's how you want to see it. I can't help you change your view there. But honestly, for a better stack experience (be it main or meta) I suggest taking downvotes differently. They aren't personal, they aren't against you, they don't mean anything about how people think about you. I know it's human nature to see it this way, but that's just self-destructive in a place like Stack...

Comment: We've told you what we want you to change about your question in these comments. If you choose not to provide it then you'll probably get downvotes as the question is not answerable in its current form. Downvotes are for other readers, not you.

Comment: Just to be clear, that declination reason was handwritten by the moderator who handled the flag. It is not a standardized value that could automatically come with a link.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ... or maybe scripted, you are saying. Ok, good to know.

Comment: @B--rian _"Many people (including me) perceive a downvote without a comment as demotivating, unwelcoming, maybe even rude."_ No, it's pretty much the opposite. If you don't have to say anything nice, say nothing. The tooltips at the voting buttons are pretty much enough to explain. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta reagarding _feature-requests_ in particular.

Comment: The first downvote arrived so quickly as a signature of the toxic atmosphere of this meta site. It is unlikely, that anybody cound find, open, read, understand and evaluate your post in seconds. It seems, we can't do too much with it in the foreseeable future, however, they can't affect your reputation (any time if you strongly suspect a main site downvote as a revenge to a meta activity, never let it without any action). *In my opinion, the site requires exactly those posts which are downvoted in seconds. So you did it imho well.*

Comment: Wow, what a storm of a discussion. I really appreciate it. Concerning the "not feeling too welcome" - I fully understand that is a rating about the question, not about the author, nevertheless it is emotionally connected. I was mentioning that as a general observation, which demotivates new users and hinders user-growth. I have actual statistics about these "unknown unknowns", the reason why great programmers do *not* join SO.

Comment: Some of the comments are derailing to a different subject than the one defined in the question. It might be worth looking for other questions (or ask a new one) in Meta for that side issue.

Comment: I know what the vast majority of people here consider to to be “toxic”, and it ain’t the voting...

Comment: @Clive Voting only shows the attitude of the voters. Also you know very well, getting the first down within seconds is a clear signature of an obviously unfair vote.

Comment: All my votes are fair @peterh

Comment: @rene I have no way to check that. I have no way to know on this meta site, exactly how many seconds lasted from the post creation until the first down. But I know that it is a problem, because also I've faced it many times, and I think we all know, what these quick downs show.

Comment: I don't really see the added value of this feature-request. There is already a lot of information available about (declined) flags on this meta site and there are a couple chat rooms where you can ask about (declined) flags.

Comment: @AndréKool Let me try to rephrase: As I learned from JoshCaswell, the flag denial reason is a text entered somebody, and if the text is not specific or prone to misunderstandings, there is a need for quick & easy accessible additional information (other than meta or elsewhere which adds an additional threshold). As we see in the discussion here, there are lots of emotions involved in voting - my request to have more transparency might also contribute to more positive atmosphere.

Comment: The decision not to implement direct messages (see e.g. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297562 ) was made in order to avoid personal verbal attacks, but would have been a solution to obtain more information e.g. about a flag, by simply asking the person. Once again, in other words: How dan I *fast* learn more about a flag reason I don't understand?

Comment: I really don't see the connection between voting and flagging.

Comment: You flagged a downvoted and closed *question* with a custom flag: *The negative shore already indicates it. There is not much hope that this becomes a valid question, so I suggest to delete it altogether.* which was declined with *there are already processes which do this automatically.* The flag is telling that your flag was redundant, please don’t ask moderators to do work that automated processes can take care of.

Comment: The next declined flag in your history was a NAA flag on an answer, which was a normal attempt at answering. It was declined with the standard flag decline reason: *flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer*. See [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552) for details on when the NAA flag is appropriate

Comment: Of course, downvotes on meta _must_ mean that meta is toxic. It couldn't _possibly_ mean that the users voting think that the question shows a lack of research effort (the premise of the question being that they literally do not want to do any research whatsoever), nor could it be that they think that the question or the feature proposed are not useful. Don't worry, it has nothing to do with the reasoning provided in the downvote tooltip, it's just the meta crowd being toxic. _smh_.

Comment: @TinyGiant The first downvote arrived in just seconds after the creation of the post. "It is unlikely, that anybody cound find, open, read, understand and evaluate your post in seconds."

Comment: @peterh unlikely, yes. But here I am, down voting in seconds.

Comment: @peterh: how do you know if the post was downvoted within seconds? There is no record of when votes were cast on Meta other that’s the date.

Comment: I am curious as to how the OP determined who reviewed their flags, since the first flag was a moderator-only custom flag, and the NAA flag also was handled by a moderator.

Comment: @perterh: at any rate, this question is filled with numerous misunderstandings about flagging, lacks details on the flags cast or how the OP determined who had declined the flags, and certainly shows a lack of research. So the voting on it is far from surprising.

Comment: @MartijnPieters 1) The OP said in a comment or in a previous version of his post 2) Also I've faced the phenomenon many times (downvote arrives so quickly which is impossible to be fair) 3) Although it is not visible on this meta site, the exact time of the down is visible on the rep history of the owner (the DOM contains the exact timestamp). The timestamp of the post creation is also public data. It can't be done on the MSO because here votes don't affect the reputation. But, for example it can be on the MSE, and on the main sites, it is possible. | Here I had to believe what the OP said,

Comment: @MartijnPieters what wasn't very hard, because also I experienced this many times. (Btw, this time I didn't get surprising main site downs to my ancient posts, I think it is a positive development.)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I can also imagine, that these seconds-after-post downs are generated by some automatized solution. Probably it is considered a serious privilege misuse, and probably the SE has no way to detect them. But maybe.

Comment: @peterh: SE can detect automated votes that arrive in a pattern. That's not the case here, you are just being paranoid now.

Comment: @MartijnPieters To detect from something that it is the output of a program, or it was generated by humans, is theoretically impossible. In my opinion, the most what SE can do, that they have some filtering/alarming mechanism for a list of pre-defined patterns.

Comment: It seems to me this discussion has nothing to do with the actual question here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Of course I have no way to know, exactly for what patterns are they filtering. But on indirect signatures, I think I can be nearly sure: giving many downs just in seconds after the post creation doesn't initiate anything by them. It is simply a non-issue for them, "paranoia", just like for you.

Answer (score 10):

> I flagged a duplicate, not helpful answer with just source code (rated -6 already) and another one which had (in my mind) nothing at all to do with a question.

Those are both the wrong reasons to flag an answer. If an answer can be understood and it attempts to answer a question (not even the question) but adds no value for future visitors such answers should be down voted.

If you get a custom response from a moderator reading *there are already processes which do this automatically* then you have been lucky as they spend 10 seconds extra on your flag instead of declining it with a stock reason.

Your flag (assuming you use one of the standard flags) might trigger a review-task that gets reviewed by users with access to the review queues. If the review outcome is different from what you intended, your flag ends up not being helpful. In these case you can visit a posts [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/16542372/timeline) to find the reviews it has been part of.

The result of the reviews of your suggested edits can be found in your [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8330162/b-rian?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

> it would be great if the reasons for a flag would be clickable and linked to a definition.

There way too many options to link every declined flag to a ready made definition. Meta and the Help centre has already plenty of feedback, background and guidance on flagging and if you can't find anything coming close to what describes your case, make sure to head over to [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/declined-flags).

> I would love to have an easy ways to have a veto or at least ask for another review.

No, let's not have features that enable too many of us being able to continue to hammer a single post until it is in the state you want it in. We have enough roll-back edit wars and re-open/close hammer wars already. We're not going to be bogged down by allowing everyone here to be that *someone is wrong on the internet* type of person.

The flagging process is fine as it is, with its current quirks. It only needs careful flaggers and foremost frivolous (down) voters.

Comment: I did not call a moderator a bot, but it is true that there might be moderators using scripts to flag. My point: I am fine with getting my flags denied by bots or humans, but I still would love to quickly understand why, hopefully without consulting meta.

Comment: You won't learn a thing about declined flags if you rule out meta. We have a [meta-tag:faq] for a reason.

Comment: My suggestion is to have an alternative, quick way to learn about her/his flagging reasons, other than meta. Not everybody likes to spend loads of time on meta, but exactly these low-frequency posters might add a great value to SO. I know so many amazing, knowledgeable programmers who could contribute, but decided not to because of the flagging and downvoting. My suggestion might help to keep these low-frequency high-value contributers motivated, and one way of doing so is to make the flag-reason more transparent.

Comment: @B--rian "without consulting meta" the primary source of information regarding flagging and the mechanics and policies around flagging is meta. This is like saying "I'd love to learn how to write software by only reading obfuscated code, without ever opening a book or reading documentation of any sort"

Comment: @Tiny Giant. I understand your point, but my point is a different one, see my comment above. My idea is defining flag-denial reasons in a concise, accessible way, as addition to and maybe teaser for meta.

Comment: There are 2000 flags handled per day by moderators, adding extra time to their workload is not going to help the quality of the posts, specially if it is only to guide an occasional mis-flagger that should be able to gather info easily by other means. You're trying to optimize the wrong end of the flag process

Comment: @rene Very insightful information I was not aware of, but please also see my concern - of loosing not acquiring new community members.

Comment: I don't see the connection between declined flag reasons and community growth. Not everything that goes wrong here needs a spin on welcoming and sustained growth. I only care about the quality of the content and the process govern that quality boost. The rest doesn't matter.

Comment: @B--rian not to sound dismissive, but saying 'they want to help and participate in the community but don't want to go on meta for feedback' is a bit like saying 'well they want to be part of the conmunity, except.... Not really'

Answer (score -15):

You have no way to know, who evaluated your flag. It can happen for a "very low quality" or "not an answer" flag, but it is not easy - you have to check the reviewers of that day in the VLQ queue, and then check their activity history on their user page. However, the effect of such evaluations can't result a textual answer with the decline.

If you get a textual answer, it should have been a diamond moderator. Ordinary mortals have no way to know, which one did it. Sometimes, knowing the sites and the mods, we can estimate it from their wordings, or if you get some surprisingly detailed reasoning after a mod election, you can suspect that it might have been a newly elected mod. However, this all is not important.

In general, you are not expected to create only accepted flags. You don't know and can't know everything on which a mod decides. What is expected, to act in good faith and know the rules. If you get many declined flags, you might get a flag ban (it happens very rarely), but even that is not a reason to stop flagging from the moment that you can do it again. It is a reason to check your flag history and think about, why did you collect so many declines. Note also, being on flag ban doesn't get away any privilege from you and it is not visible for anybody (maybe except the mods).

If one really wants, can misuse this leniency (for example, by flooding the mods with crap flags), obviously you shouldn't do ever any similar, but that is all.

So: don't worry, don't stop flagging, don't worry on induvidual declines, and don't stop writing good posts and suggest good initatives on the meta site.

Comment: If someone doesnt understand why their flag was declined they should most definitely attempt to find more information. Whether that be searching for questions about similar declines on meta, or asking a meta question if they still don't understand. Saying that they should just not worry about it is very bad advice in my opinion.

Comment: @TinyGiant This is not on induvidual declines, but if there is also a tendency. What I explained: *"It is a reason to check your flag history and think about, why did you collect so many declines."*